# How to write at my own MQTT client code without using any API

Tags: sockets, client, mqtt, iot

I'd like to ask for recommendations. I want to write a client program using MQTT to publish data to the broker. I can´t use any client libraries available in the internet. I would like to ask where can I find examples that works similar to this as an inspiration for my work, or any suggestions regarding the steps I should follow is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you use an existing client library? Also what language are you intending to implement you application in? Asking for examples is explicitly off topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I can´t use existing libraries because I am supposed to learn from scratch. Then maybe you can suggest the steps I can follow. I am using C

Comment: There is no good reason not use an existing library unless you have been explicitly been told to write a client library, the only reason you would be told to do this as school project. In which case the only document you should be reading is the MQTT spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you have to know well the MQTT protocol, in order to use adequately commands and messages needed to perform the communication.

Regarding the protocol, you can find documentation in the [official page](http://mqtt.org/documentation) and a good explanation in [this HiveMQ page](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-3-client-broker-connection-establishment/). One example of a simple MQTT client implementation, in Java, can be seen [in this tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/write_your_own_mqtt_client_without_using_any_api_in_minutes1?lang=en).